# PHPUnit: Class <ClassName> could not be found in <ClassNameTest>.php

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

I'm at my wit's end. I must have read every SO question on the same topic, but no joy.

I can't get phpUnit working properly. I've successfully installed phpUnit and it's dependencies using PEAR. I've also modified my php.ini file and added the path to phpUnit to the include path: (".:/php/includes:usr/lib/php/pear").

To test phpunit is working, I've copied this simple class, so MyClassTest.php is as follows:

```
class MyClassTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function testCalculate()
    {
        $this->assertEquals(2, 1 + 1);
    }
}
```

Running "phpunit MyClassTest" produces the following output: (running "phpunit MyTestClass MyTestClass.php" produces the same result);

```
class MyClassTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function testCalculate()
    {
        $this->assertEquals(2, 1 + 1);
    }
}
PHPUnit 3.7.13 by Sebastian Bergmann.

Class 'MyClassTest' could not be found in 'MyClassTest.php'.
```

I can't think what's wrong. I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling phpunit/PHPUnit, but no joy. Can you identify what's wrong? If you need any more info, let me know and I'll edit this post. Thanks in advance.

- PHP 5.3.15
- PHPUnit 3.7.13
- OSX 10.8.2

Comment: Is it actually displaying the code from the MyClassTest.php file?

Comment: Yes, it is. Not sure why. All examples I've seen don't mention anything like it.

Comment: The examples shouldn't need to mention a missing <?php it is required for all PHP scripts

Comment: Grr!! That was the problem! Well spotted Mark. I was so focused on the installation/config that I didn't even consider the source file being the problem. Lesson learned. Thanks again!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your source code gets printed to the console, so it seems like you forgot `<?php` at the beginning.

Comment: I initially thought that this was the case too. Tried it with the require statement. No change.

Comment: I edited the answer after realizing that PHPUnit comes with an autoloader in newer versions and the require statement is not necessary anymore. But @Mark Baker gave an important hint in the comments.

Comment: Had the same issue since I was using the PHP short form <?

Comment: I have just spotted, that you must use full form of PHP starting tags, so short tags doesn't work.

**<?** - doesn't work
**<?php** - does work